# what does this backslash mean in this bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sudo

I encountered this tool called neofetch on this server but I don't know what are those characters at the end for, can somebody explain it to me?
I know that the single backslash is an escape character in bash, but what about it in this case?
the output is from a sudo -l command.

```
/usr/bin/neofetch \"\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash (`\`) is used to escape the quotes (`"`). Without the backshlashs, you'd have:

```
/usr/bin/neofetch ""
```

The shell would interpret `""` as an empty string and call `neofetch` with that (an empty string, that is).

By escaping the quotes, you're able to call `neofetch` with `""`.

Comment: thank you! whats the point in having empty quotes then if no args are added in them? does it really matter or could've been ok also without them? like just /usr/bin/neofetch \

Answer (score 1):

it just prints `""`.

you can always try it with `echo \"\"` in the terminal.

In this case it's just to escape `""` itself which should be interpret as an empty string by the shell; by escaping it you are passing `""` itself as an argument to your  `neofetch` call.

Comment: thanks man! yeah i tried that echo command before asking, was just wondering on the point of having quotes without args in them, why not just have /usr/bin/neofetch \  ?

Comment: backslash at the end just make shell ignore the newline while executing a command so you still have to pass an arg to the script you are executing. but with `\"\"`, you laterally pass no arg to the `neofetch` and it gives you a brief about your system back. cause there is a list of args that you can call `neofetch` with, like memory or cpu. However, the same could be done just with calling `neofetch`.

Comment: However, `neofetch` doesn't care what you are passing as arg. if what you are passing is not a defined function it just ignores it. check [here](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/blob/ccd5d9f52609bbdcd5d8fa78c4fdb0f12954125f/neofetch#L5505)

Comment: perfect, thanks for the help! all clear :)